# What functionality of iOS can be accessed from the lock screen?

Tags: ios, screen-lock

I know that in iOS, several parts of the iDevice's functionality can be accessed from the lock screen. This is useful when you don't want to fumble with a password.

But now I'm starting to wonder: what else can be accessed from the lock screen? I know these:

- Three-home-button tap to invert screen (when Universal Access is enabled)
- Double tap to play music

What else can be accessed from the iOS lock screen?

### EDIT:

As Daniel L mentioned,

> "It shouldn't produce a bunch of partial answers; a good answer will
>   include a canonical listing (with sources) of what can be accessed
>   from the iOS lock screen. There is a right answer to this question."

Please, make your answer a canonical listing (with sources) of what can be accessed from the iOS lock screen.

Comment: On my iOS 5.1 iPhone, nothing happens with 4x Home taps.

Comment: @KatieK: hmm. Just tried it with a 4.x device and it seems to work. Maybe it's 3 taps?

Comment: This should probably be a community wiki question.

Comment: @KatieK It's a setting. I believe it is under Universal Access or the like.

Comment: It shouldn't produce a bunch of partial answers; a good answer will include a canonical listing (with sources) of what can be accessed from the iOS lock screen. There is a right answer to this question.

Comment: @DanielL: Yes, I agree. I'll give the green check to whoever does that the best.

Answer (score 3):

I'm including the ones mentioned in your answer in the name of having a complete listing in one place.

- **Toggle music controls** (Play/Pause, Previous, Next, Volume) by double tapping the home button.
- **Take pictures** and videos by sliding the camera button.
- **Invoke accessibility features** by triple clicking the home button. Configurable in Settings-> General-> Accessibility-> Triple Click Home. You can configure toggling VoiceOver, toggling White on Black, toggling Zoom, or asking which to do.
- **Make phone calls** by tapping the Emergency Call button and dialing a number. iPhones only.
- **View snippets of emails, text messages, and other notifications** by looking at their  notification preview. Configurable in Settings-> Notifications-> *App*.
- **Activate Siri** to make calls, send text messages, send emails, get directions, check calendars, etc. by holding down the home button. Configurable in Settings-> General-> Passcode Lock. iPhone 4S only.
- **Take a screenshot** by pressing the home button and sleep/wake button at the same time.
- **Power the device off** by holding down the sleep/wake button.

Comment: Awesome. Finally, a decent answer. Is this a complete answer? If it is, I'd like a source.

Comment: Not sure if this is complete; it's just what I've been able to find myself. Since this is just based on personal experience, I don't have a source. Feel free to test though :)

Comment: I can't think of anything else other than the static information displayed (Carrier, Connectivity [3G, 4G, WiFi], battery life, and the time).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with iOS 5, the camera can be accessed from the lockscreen (obviously only on devices that have a camera). On iOS 5.0.x, double-clicking the home button reveals a camera button next to the unlock slider that can be clicked, and in iOS 5.1, there is a permanent camera button that you slide up to reveal the camera under the lockscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an older flowchart that gives a good overview of the home button features, and on the right side what you can do starting from the lock screen:

[image]

Comment: I see the lock screen stuff starting on the right, not left.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know what qualifies as the features you know about and what is "else", but one other new feature is accessing notifications on the lock screen by swiping them.

Comment: I suppose the clock could also be considered a feature :)

Comment: What I mean here is any kind of functionality that can be accessed from the lock screen. I don't care if it is something I know, but please don't make it one of the 2 I mentioned in the question.